# fate error : Cant find file 'sal.h'

Tags: window, directx, visual-c++

I am a beginner of book《Tricks of the 3D Game Programming》.

But VC6.0 shows Cant find 'sal.h' when I compile the source code of book.

I don't know how to solve this kind of problem..

PS. I am a Chinese student, my English isn't very well, so forgive me for my grammar false.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Windows header, there must be a problem with your include path.

Check your default C++ include file path (in
Tools-->Options. In the dialog box, click on the Directories tab), it should be

```
$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include
```

Comment: I used VC++, I can not find project/properties item. I can only find project/setings..